# Plugins not updated when building eclipse P2 update site

Tags: eclipse

I have created an eclipse update site (using Helios) and added some features (containing my own plug-ins available in the target platform ). I then synchronized the site and build it which creates two folders: features and plugins containing the plugins and features  (.jar files).

I then make some changes to one of the plugins in the feature, update the feature and the update site and build it again. But the resulting plugin in the plugins folder is not updated!

How do I force the update site to produce the updated plugins in the plugins folder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One key idea to force an update: make sure, the version of the new build is different from the old one. The simplest way to achieve this is to use a version number like 1.0.0.qualifier This way during build the current date and time is added to the fourth number of the version.

I also suggest not using update site projects, but simply exporting deployable features. For details see [my blog entry](http://cubussapiens.hu/en/2010/08/update-sites-in-the-p2-era/) (sorry for advertising myself :) ). This way works much easier.

Comment: I already use: 1.0.0.qualifier but its still does not rebuild the plugins. I will check your blog! But even though I rebuild the site completely form scratch its still the old versions from the folder:

C:\Users\mm\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\.bundle_pool\plugins

that are used in the project. So the problem is just moved to this step.

Comment: Maybe you forced an explicit version in the update site project? It is possible to set the update project to always use a specific version instead of synchronizing with the current plugin versions?

You could check this by looking the contents of the built jar file, whether it contains the newer or older ones (just overwritten the old one with the new contents).

Comment: You don't have to apologize if your blog entry is good, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's probably not the textbook answer, but I used to delete all previous outputs and sync again before each build.

Eventually, I switched to the [PDE-Build tool](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/PDEBuild). It's a headless script which is much more stable than the UI based build. It takes time to master, but, if you do this on a regular basis and you need consistent results, it is worth the effort.