# eclipse update site not updating

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I'm producing plugin's for eclipse - but for some reason when I build a new version of the plugin - the update site isn't noticing it.

The build process says that the plugins should be at version 1.1.0.201209191506, but when I access to install I'm shown these versions:

[image]

The XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<site>
   <feature url="features/supportStructuresForCSFEditing -_1.1.0.201209191506.jar" id="supportStructuresForCSFEditing -" version="1.1.0.201209191506">
      <category name="plancomps"/>
   </feature>
   <feature url="features/supportStructuresForCSFEditingTest -_1.1.0.201209191506.jar" id="supportStructuresForCSFEditingTest -" version="1.1.0.201209191506">
      <category name="plancomps"/>
   </feature>
   <category-def name="plancomps" label="plancomps"/>
</site>
```

and this happens if I'm installing from local or from the web - any idea what might be happening? Or diagnostic tricks I could try?

EDIT - there have been restarts of the machine - and attempts from machines that have never seen the plugin's before - all have shown the old versions. :(

Comment: Did you update any specific plug-in?? or general eclipse update is not working?

Comment: These two specific plugins are the ones I'm developing - I changed them, re-build them, and want to install them into a test instance of eclipse - but I keep being shown the old versions of the plugin :(

Comment: I think you have to change one of the first 3 parts of the version, changing the 4th part (the build id) is ignored.

Comment: Here is a working solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3491964/632199 Just don't create an update site project. Export deployable feature instead. The export wizard will create all needed metadata.

Answer (score 4):

I'd check two things.

1) I think that due to a bug, sometimes features are removed from category (if you use GUI to update your site). So you might be looking at your plug-ins in your category, when latest version is at top level or vice-versa.

2) Eclipse caches current state of update site. So you need to restart, to make it show newer versions.

Comment: Embarrasingly I find myself coming back over over a year to say that I'm having the same problem again - and that restarting didn't make a difference unfortunately...

Comment: Thanks. In my case the feature got removed from the category. Not nice but happy it is available. (I'm using neon)

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, your cache is not being updated.  p2 will often cache update site content information.  It looks like you are using old style update sites and that you do not have a content.xml(or .jar) and a artifact.xml(or .jar), which is not really supported any more and may make it harder to delete the cache.

Here are somethings you can try:

1. Help -> Install new software -> Available software sites -> (Select your update site) -> Reload
2. Delete and re-add your update site
3. Restart eclipse with the -clean option to clear out the configuration area

But, really you should be making sure that you are creating artifact.xml and content.xml (or .jar) and creating proper update sites.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so coming back to this I have a reason and a workaround.

Eclipse's caching is pretty aggressive. But something I was doing wasn't helping and I thought I'd share.

When I was building a new version of the plugin, I was deleting the previous one (which made sense to me, generally the previous one was an internal buggy thing and I could have always reconstructed it from the svn). However when I started leaving the previous versions in, the update site started working much more as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the issue is already solved for the OP, but I thought I'd share:
I just spent 2+ hours fighting with a very similar problem and finally managed to solve it. I'm not sure whether my solution can be applied to this case. My case was like this:

1. I created some plugins and uploaded them to a software site I had also created.
2. In a `default.target` file I added the plugins from that software site.
3. I realized there was an error in one of the plugins, created it again, uploaded it to the software site, and clicked "Update" for that site in my `default.target`.

The plugin never got reloaded. Even when I deleted the update site, eclipse "magically" still saw it and pretended to update from there when I clicked update. Fun fun fun.

I tried all kinds of things and this is the only one that worked for me in the end (I'm going to assume that you have a `default.target` as well):

1. Remove the plugins that aren't being updated from your `default.target`.
2. Exit eclipse (at least the instance for the problematic workspace).
3. **Backup your workspace, or at least `default.target` and** `<pathToYourWorkspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\.bundle_pool\`. It may be difficult to revert the following changes if you need to.
4. In `<pathToYourWorkspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\.bundle_pool\`:

   1. Open `artifacts.xml` and delete all references to the plugins that aren't being updated. Note that there may be multiple references to each plugin; for example in my case I have one with `'classifier='org.eclipse.update.feature'` and one with `classifier='osgi.bundle'` (I'm using OSGi).
   2. Open subdir `features` and delete the folders corresponding to the plugins that aren't being updated. (Sorting by date may help. Btw, in my case the "date modified" for those jars showed that they had only been downloaded the first time and never updated again)
   3. Open subdir `plugins` and delete the jars corresponding to the plugins that aren't being updated. (Sorting by date may help. Ditto)
5. Open eclipse again, with the options `-clean` and `-data <pathToYourWorkspace>` so that it cleans the workspace.
6. Add the plugins to `default.target`.
7. If there are still problems try selecting the plugins or update site and clicking "Update", and/or restarting eclipse.

This almost drove me crazy. I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

I think you first use a fresh copy of eclipse to add a plugin,if that plugin is already installed.Copy eclipse.zip in new folder,unzip it ,run eclipse and then start using update site to do this please

Help-->Install new software-->"paste update site url"-->It will catch updates-->click ok-->accept license-->"continue process"-->It gives a warning press Ok " now you are success in updating.

Note:An internet connection should be properly available.