# IBM / HCL Notes with Eclipse: Update Site Project not building

Tags: java, eclipse, lotus-notes

I have an eclipse plugin, a feature and an update site project which builds fine in a version on IBM Notes 9.x. With "builds fine" I mean that the plugin´s jar files are built in the plugins and feature folder through the action "Build All" in the update site project.
After upgrading to IBM / HCL Notes 10.0.1 FP 3 the action "Build All" displays the dialog "Generating Ant Scripts" for a short time and finishes, no new jar´s are generated.
I have various VMwares where building the exactly same project is OK (I have it on a shared drive) and some which behave like described. I think all of version Notes 10 dont build fine.
Searching for a solution of this problem didnt bring any helpful results, like [Plugins not updated when building eclipse P2 update site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491560/plugins-not-updated-when-building-eclipse-p2-update-site).

Does anyone have same experiences and a solution ?

Comment: Use the right eclipse version, (I'm using 4.62 32bit for this at the moment) import your project and compile it against the Notes JVM and the Notes target platform.

Comment: Thank you for the idea - I installed the Eclipse IDE and wondered how to get the "Build" or "Build All" button in the update site project. Then I found out that there is the Plug-in Development Environment (PDE). After installing it and changing some setting the plugin is built !!! Great, thanks again !